# Price-Volume-Mix Analysis in managerial accounting - choice of the right formula for mix

Tags: finance

My question is about Price-Volume-Mix analysis in the area of managerial accounting or business controlling. Other people also call it profit-margin variance analysis, and other names might exist. But the goal of the analysis is to understand the contributing factors that drive up or down the profit-margin. The main contributing factors are sales volume, sales price, unit cost, mix and etc.

My question is mainly about the **mix calculation**. 
So far I’ve seen two different ways of calculating mix effect. And the two ways appear to have different intentions and thus different mathematics formula behind.

---

**Method 1**:

Step 1 **Mix% (Quantity) Variance** = (*Sales quantity of Product A in 2016)/(Sales quantity of Total in 2016) –  (Sales quantity of Product A in 2015)/(Sales quantity of Total in 2015*)

Step 2 **Mix Effect on Profit** = **Mix% (Quantity) Variance** × *Sales quantity of Total in 2016 × (Sales Price in 2015 – Unit Cost in 2015)*

**Method 2**:

Step 1 **Mix% (Revenue) Variance** = *(Sales Revenue of Product A in 2016)/(Sales Revenue of Total in 2016) –  (Sales Revenue of Product A in 2015)/(Sales Revenue of Total in 2015)*

Step 2 **BPR Difference** = *Product A’s Profit Margin% in 2015 – Total Profit Margin% in 2015*

Step 3 **Mix Effect on Profit** = **Mix% (Revenue) Variance** × **BPR Difference** × Total Sales Revenue 2016

---

I used to use method 1, but just got to know method 2 recently. Though I am not a mathematic specialist, I feel the BPR difference in method 2 not fit into the context of the analysis. The price-volume-mix is to compare across two periods (or compare realized with budget), while the BPR difference is comparing the margin of one individual product to the total margin. As I perceived, multiplying with BPR **will change the course of the initial comparison of two periods**, thus become irrelevant to the cross-period price-volume-mix analysis. What do everyone think, or correct me if I am wrong?

There're also other differences between the two methods such as the mix% variance calculation based on quantity versus revenue.

You can find the literature about method 2 here:
http://www.volume-and-mix-analysis.com/uploads/1/7/0/2/17027570/mix_matters.pdf

http://www.volume-and-mix-analysis.com/uploads/1/7/0/2/17027570/mix_variances_in_profit_rate_analysis.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**My Answer (Method 2):**

Method 2 subsumes that all price and cost variances have been previously eliminated in the analysis; it is **Mix Analysis** *only*.  It does ***not*** address price and cost variances; it does **not** intend to do so.  It directly addresses *only* the pure mathematics of **mix variance**.  Price and cost variances should have already been eliminated/recognized via other methodologies.  In other words, the following mathematical identity is imperative and **must** be implicitly recognized:

***Product A’s Profit Margin% in 2016 == Product A’s Profit Margin% in 2015***

The ***Total Profit Margin% in 2015***  is a simple "weighted average" (weighted by the mix of products which comprise the total).  The **BPR Difference** is static for 2015 in that it remains a **constant** no matter what the 2016 vs 2015 mix deltas become.  Thus it has no "*cross-period*" affect.  The **only** numerical functionality which affects mix variance is the variability of the **Mix% Variance** (the mix delta) of Step 1.

The mix algorithm's methodology works equally well on quantity (*Units and Profit/Unit*) or revenue (*Sales and Profit/Sales$*).  The usage simply depends upon what is most meaningful in the particular managerial accounting scenario.